# Spring Boot, H2 and Flyway: run integration tests with two versions of the database

Tags: spring-boot, flyway

For blue/green deployment, it is required that the new application version run with both the old and the new database version. So my integration tests should run twice: with previous database version (partial migration to version-1) and then with latest version.

I could do this by setting up a local MySQL database and handle the migration and test running manually but I wonder if there is a way to use H2 and automate the process somehow for CI.

I have a very basic Spring Boot/Flyway setup.

application.yaml:

```
spring:
  profiles: db_h2
  ...
flyway:
  locations: classpath:/flyway/h2,classpath:/flyway/common,classpath:/flyway/testdata
```

test parent class:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = Application.class, webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
@TestExecutionListeners({DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.class, FlywayTestExecutionListener.class })
@ActiveProfiles({"db_h2","logging_quiet", "http_secure_selfsigned", "credentials_insecure"})
public abstract class RestIntTestParent {
   ...
    @Before
    @FlywayTest
    public void setUpAll() throws Exception {
        ...
    }
}
```

an example of a REST Assured test:

```
public class SettingsIntTest extends RestIntTestParent {
    private static final String URL = "/users/me/settings";

    @Test
    public void testGetAll() {
        final String authTokenAlice = getAuthToken("alice");

        given(this.specApi)
            .header(AUTH_HEADER, authTokenAlice)
            .get(URL)
        .then()
            .statusCode(HttpStatus.OK.value())
            .body("content", hasSize(4))
            .body("content[3].intVal1", equalTo(28))
            .body("content[1].jsonVal[2].year", equalTo(2015));
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think there is an easier way of how to do this than manually create two classes and override URL or something like that